# Test stream in akka test kit using Java

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-testkit.html

I am using akka using Java can anyone tell me how system is intialized in the code

```
final Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Integer>> sinkUnderTest =
Flow.of(Integer.class)
    .map(i -> i * 2)
    .toMat(Sink.fold(0, (agg, next) -> agg + next), Keep.right());

final CompletionStage<Integer> future =
Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)).runWith(sinkUnderTest, system);
final Integer result = future.toCompletableFuture().get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
assert (result == 20);
```

`static ActorSystem system =ActorSystem.create()` does not work in

```
Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)).runWith(sinkUnderTest, system);
```

Comment: When you say 'ActorSystem.create() does not work', how does it manifest itself? Does it throw an exception or what?

Comment: Works for me. What behaviour are you experiencing when you run it and what imports and dependencies are you using?

Comment: it gives compile error and expects a materializer with runwith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

As you are using the akka 2.5 with the 2.12 api instead, you will have to create a materializer as described in the quickstart section for the matching documentation, check [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-quickstart.html).

```java
private ActorSystem system;
private Materializer materializer;

@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    system = ActorSystem.create("StreamTestKitDocTest");
    materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);
}

// ...

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    // ...
    Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)).runWith(sinkUnderTest, materializer);
    // ...
}
```

---

As you are saying it does not even compile for you, I assume you have an issue either with your dependencies or your imports. A common mistake is that instead of the java dsl you import the scala versions accidentally.

Here the dependencies and code I used to verify that its working (Tested with Java 1.8):

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-stream-testkit_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

JUnit Test case:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Keep;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;

public class AkkaTest {

    private ActorSystem system;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        system = ActorSystem.create("StreamTestKitDocTest");
    }

    @After
    public void shutdown() {
        system.terminate();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

        final Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Integer>> sinkUnderTest =
        Flow.of(Integer.class)
            .map(i -> i * 2)
            .toMat(Sink.fold(0, (agg, next) -> agg + next), Keep.right());

        final CompletionStage<Integer> future =
        Source.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)).runWith(sinkUnderTest, system);
        final Integer result = future.toCompletableFuture().get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Assert.assertEquals(20, result.intValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: What I see is that whether under java dsl or scala dsl , all files are in *.scala in jar, not sure why

Comment: I am using dependencies in gradle testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2'
   testImplementation "com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-testkit_2.12:2.5"
   implementation "com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.5"

Comment: That version uses a different API. I added the correct link for the documentation and a short example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the source code of example?
[source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.6.0/akka-docs/src/test/java/jdocs/stream/StreamTestKitDocTest.java#L47-L55)

```
  static ActorSystem system;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup() {
    system = ActorSystem.create("StreamTestKitDocTest");
  }
```